# Prove that every degree one representation $\rho: G \to \mathbb{C}^{∗}$ is of the form $\psi \circ \phi$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$. That is, $G'$ is the subgroup of G generated by all commutators $[g, h] = g^{−1}h^{−1}gh$ with
$g, h \in G$. You may take for granted the following facts that are typically proved in a first course in group theory:

1. $G'$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
2. $\frac{G}{G'}$ is an abelian group.
3. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $\frac{G}{N}$ is an abelian if and only if $G' \subseteq N$.

Let $\phi : G \to \frac{G}{G'}$ be the canonical homomorphism given by $\phi(g) = gG'$. Prove that every degree one representation $\rho: G \to \mathbb{C}^{∗}$ is of the form $\psi \circ \phi$ where $\psi : \frac{G}{G'} \to \mathbb{C}^{∗}$ is a degree one representation of the abelian group $\frac{G}{G'}$.

I know that $\psi \circ \phi$ is a representation but how can we prove that every representation of degree 1 can be written like this? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $1$-dimensional is just a group homomorphism $\rho$ from $G$ to $\Bbb C^*$
and $\Bbb C^*$ is an Abelian group. This means that $\rho([g,h])=1$
as $\rho([g,h])=\rho(g)^{-1}\rho(h)^{-1}\rho(g)\rho(h)$. So $\rho$
is trivial on each commutator, and so on $G'$, the group they generate.
So $\rho$ factors through $G/G'$....